# No click effect on CardView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using an `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and I dynamically add new elements that have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        style="@style/cardView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/direction_list_icon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/direction_list_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dummy text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem is that I see click effect on `CardView` item only when I doubleclick on it or making an long click.**

I tried to place an `LinearLayout` inside `CardView` and make in clickable with `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` but result stays the same

Comment: Problem was solved only by replacing RecyclerView with GridView.

Comment: but what if I want to use RecyclerView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem in my project by setting background to the `CardView`'s root element. In your layout this should work:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    style="@style/cardView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

on your CardView